# media queries don't work after jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries

I use media queries to change width and height of some `div`s when window is resized. I also use jQuery to make them bigger on mouseover. But when jQuery is executed media queries stop working and after resize `div`s have same width and height as was set in jQuery and style from media queries isn't applied on `div`s.

Sorry for my bad English.

css

```
@media only screen and (max-width:1100px)
{
 .kruh
 {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
 }
}
@media only screen and (max-width:850px)
{
 .kruh
 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
 }
}
```

and jQuery

```
var s = $("#kruh1").width();
var d=s+10;

$("#kruh1").mouseover(function()
 {
   $("#kruh1").animate({width: d+"", height: d+""}, );
 });

$("#kruh1").mouseout(function()
 {
   $("#kruh1").animate({width: s+"", height: s+""}, );
 });
```

Comment: You used class as css selector and id as jquery object. What is html content? It has class and id with the same name or you missed that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for jQuery here. CSS is perfect for the job.

```
.kruh {
  transition: transform 0.4s ease;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:1100px) {
  .kruh {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
  }
  .kruh:hover {
    transform: scale(1.07);
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width:850px) {
  .kruh {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
  .kruh:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
}
```

Please note that in your CSS you're targetting an element with the **class** `.kruh`. In your jQuery you're targetting an element with the **id** `#kruh1`.

As long as you don't show the HTML as well, noone can be certain if their help works for you.

Comment: One more think. Divs are circles and after change scale by 1.07 they magnify perfecly but also they slide down around 50px and i dont want to do that. Do you know how to fix it please?

Comment: `transform-origin: center center;`

Comment: Thank you so much transform ogigin wasnt solution but  i delete  transform: translateX(-50%);
transform: translateY(-50%); and now it works perfectly